# Config Parser Python - How to read from json file?

Tags: python, json, parsing, config

I have created a `profile.json` file in the same folder as my `script/.py` is. It looks something like:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "age": "",
    "city": "",
}
```

I'm looking to insert it into my script that got headers of:

```
"info": {
    "given_name": "",
    "given_Lastname": "",
    "given_age": "",
    "given_city": ""
}
```

I'm wondering how can I make it possible to read from my `profile.json` into my script? This is my first time using this and I'm also new into Python. I feel like this could be an easy way to modify information WITHOUT having to change the code every time.

EDIT:

Tried to do this:

with open('profile.json', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)
    print(config)

then:

```
"info": 
       {
         "given_name": config.given_name
       }
```

the print is saying good information but when it comes to **"given_name": config.given_name** then im getting a error saying

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'given_name'`

Comment: Use the json python package: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html

Comment: I can't really find where you can use your file into the script from that documenation. Either i am blind or it is not there

Comment: `with open('<file_path>') as fp: json.load(fp)` See [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: But does that mean like etc if I send the file to my laptop from desktop. I need to change my file path everytime?

Comment: Could you show the result of `print(config)`?

Comment: It wont even allow me to run the program. So I cant even print the config.

Comment: Print it without doing the second part to check if the error is thrown when loading the JSON file.

Comment: Oh the reason was because apprently my Json file was not validated. I used json validate and it fixed the issue.

Comment: You need to enclose the property in quotes...

Comment: And use proper json syntax. This isn't so much a python question as it is a json issue. Go read the json rfc.

Comment: Oh well. Apprently I did now correct Json but it gives me ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'``` and in my script it is ```"given_name": config.name```

Comment: And also I printed out my Json file and it is correct. All information is correct.

Comment: @CharlesAddis im still having a issue with it!

Comment: Does it have to be JSON? You can avoid the deserialization issues if you just import a python file with your configuration data in it. Just a suggestion if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access a dictionary key as an attribute (ie: `config["given_name"]` vs `config.given_name`. You've also changed your question multiple times, but what you are trying to do (I think) is simple. For the trivial example you've given, where you have a json file with only one json object in it, this may be closer to what you're trying to do:

*Note: Your json syntax is wrong, it should be `{ "info": { ... } }`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''profile.json:
{
    "name": "steve",
    "lastname": "jobs",
    "age": "70",
    "city": "heaven"
}
'''
import json
import io


# Open the JSON File and create a StringIO buffer to hold data
with open('profile.json', 'r') as datafile, io.StringIO() as data:
    # Load data into json file
    config = json.load(datafile)
    # Build json strong
    data.write(f'''{{
            \r\t"info": {{
            \r\t\t"given_name": "{config['name']}",
            \r\t\t"given_Lastname": "{config['lastname']}",
            \r\t\t"given_age": "{config['age']}",
            \r\t\t"given_city": "{config['city']}"
            \r\t}}\n}}''')
    print(data.getvalue())
    # open a new file to save the data (overwrite if it exists)
    with open('newfile.json', 'w') as outfile:
        # load the json string and dump to outfile
        deserialized = json.loads(data.getvalue())
        json.dump(deserialized, outfile)
        # newfile.json:
        #{
        #        "info": {
        #                "given_name": "steve",
        #                "given_Lastname": "jobs",
        #                "given_age": "70",
        #                "given_city": "heaven"
        #        }
        #}
```

That is just a trivial example with the data you gave me, so I made another example that works with a json list rather than a json dict:

```
[{
    "name": "steve",
    "lastname": "jobs",
    "age": "70",
    "city": "heaven"
},
{
    "name": "steve1",
    "lastname": "jobs1",
    "age": "71",
    "city": "heaven1"
},
{
    "name": "steve2",
    "lastname": "jobs2",
    "age": "72",
    "city": "heaven2"
},
{
    "name": "steve3",
    "lastname": "jobs3",
    "age": "73",
    "city": "heaven3"
},
{
    "name": "steve4",
    "lastname": "jobs4",
    "age": "74",
    "city": "heaven4"
}]
```

And a similar script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''profile.json:
'''
import json
import io


# Open the JSON File and create a StringIO buffer to hold data
# Note: StringIO provides a file-like interface over a string
with open('profile.json', 'r') as datafile, io.StringIO() as data:
    # Load data into json file
    config = json.load(datafile)
    # Build json strong
    data.write('{\n\t"info": [\n')
    #data.write('\t{')
    for jsonobj in config:
        data.write(f'''\t    {{
                \r\t\t"given_name": "{jsonobj['name']}",
                \r\t\t"given_Lastname": "{jsonobj['lastname']}",
                \r\t\t"given_age": "{jsonobj['age']}",
                \r\t\t"given_city": "{jsonobj['city']}"
                \r\t    }}''')

        # Note: There is a bug here.
        # This will not be able to handle duplicate objects in
        # the json list. For a trivial example like this, it works.
        if jsonobj == config[-1]:
            data.write('\n\t]\n}')
        else:
            data.write(',\n')
    # open a new file to save the data (overwrite if it exists)
    with open('newfile.json', 'w') as outfile:
        # We need to serialize the json data if we want to write to file
        deserialized = json.loads(data.getvalue())
        outfile.write(json.dumps(serialized))
        # or we can just print it
        print(serialized)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are some good suggestions from the comments on your original question.  If you want to pull in configurable data from another file you can do two options from looking at your original question.

**1. Use a json file**

It looks like this is the first suggested answer and you can configure variables that you can use in your program from this JSON file.  Assuming, the config.json file is in the current directory of your program you can do the following:

```
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config_data = json.load(config_file)
```

**2. Use a python file**

This is another option that you have just in case you don't want to deserialize the json when you load the configuration.  You can keep everything as python datatypes so you just need to import it. In this example CONFIG_INFO is simply a dictionary that you can import into other scripts that require it.  I usually use this for username/password/general configuration stuff at work.

config.py

```
CONFIG_INFO = {
    "given_name": "test name",
    "given_lastname": "test lastname",
    "given_age": 12,
    "given_city": "Seattle"
}
```

my_script.py

```
from config import CONFIG_INFO

print("Config City: {0}".format(CONFIG_INFO["given_city"]))
print("Config Name: {0}".format(CONFIG_INFO["given_name"]))
print("Config Lastname: {0}".format(CONFIG_INFO["given_lastname"]))
print("Config Age: {0}".format(CONFIG_INFO["given_age"]))
```

Comment: If he uses a json file he doesn't need to read the contents and use `loads`, `load` would be the correct function to parse json files.

Comment: Great catch @CharlesAddis.  I didn't know about the load method.  I'll get my answer updated here. Thanks!

Comment: I think the config.py needs to have "CONFIG_INFO = ". The ":" is a typo.

Comment: Corrected thanks @DrPhil!